# Distance between relations

Tags: relations

Assume I have two binary relations $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ on a set $S$, i.e., two subsets of $S \times S$. I want to compare these two relations in terms of similarity. Is there any distance metric that I can apply? The two relations are both complete, reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive. Alternatively, we could assume that both relations are irreflexive, asymmetric, transitive, and $a \neq b \Longrightarrow aRb \lor bRa$.

Comment: Perhaps you may check the Hamming metric.

Comment: Thank you, Anton. That would be the number of elements that are in one set but not in the other. Not perfectly adjusted for the problem at hand, but something to start with.

Comment: You're welcome @Florian!